# An issue with an output of a code in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, count, counter

I have a problem with my code.

my code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int min(int A[], int s)
{
    int x = A[0];
    for (int i = 0; i<s; i++)
        if (A[i]<x)
            x = A[i];
    return x;
}

int max(int A[], int s)
{
    int x = A[0];
    for (int i = 0; i<s; i++)
        if (A[i]>x)
            x = A[i];
    return x;
}


int main()
{
    int Array[10] = { 15,20,8,0,17,14,2,12,10,5 };

    while (1)
    {
        string UserInput;
        cin >> UserInput;

        if (UserInput == "Minimun")
        {
            int Minimum = min(Array, 10);
        }

        if (UserInput == "Maximum")
        {
            int Maximum = max(Array, 10);
        }

        if (UserInput == "Dropped ones")
        {
            int count = min(Array, 10) + 1;
            for (int i = min(Array, 10); i<max(Array, 10) - 1; i++)
                cout << count++ << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it has no error, but it doesn't work as I want.

If I have an array: int Array[10]= {15,20,8,0,17,14,2,12,10,5};

And I found the max and min value in this array. I want to make a counter which print the values from 0 to 20, except the values in the array.

It means that the output should be:

```
1
3
4
6
7
9
11
13
15
16
18
19
```

Why my code doesn't print this output?

Please help me, I don't know where is the wrong sentence in this code.
Thanks in advance.

Another try but give an error with "cbegin" and "cend":

```
     #include <iostream>
     #include <vector>
     #include <algorithm>

       using namespace std;

       int main()
         {
         int Array[] = { 15, 20, 8, 0, 17, 14, 2, 12, 10, 5 };

auto Minimum = *min_element( cbegin( Array ), cend( Array ) );
auto Maximum = *max_element( cbegin( Array ), cend( Array ) );

cout << "Min: " << Minimum << '\n';
cout << "Max: " << Maximum << '\n';

for( auto i = 1; i <= 20; ++i ) {
    if( find( cbegin( Array ), cend( Array ), i ) == cend( Array ) ) {
        cout << i << "\n";
    }
}

return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Since you are working with C++ you really should use `std::vector`, `std::min_element`, `std::max_element` and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your post correctly.  As per your request I changed the code from using vectors to using c arrays.  I took out the user input stuff to give you a smaller sample to look at.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Array[] = { 15, 20, 8, 0, 17, 14, 2, 12, 10, 5 };
    // part of the xutility header
    // better to use cbegin( Array );
    auto begin = &Array[ 0 ];
    // better to use cend( Array );
    auto end = begin + sizeof( Array ) / sizeof( Array[ 0 ] );

    auto Minimum = *min_element( begin, end );
    auto Maximum = *max_element( begin, end );

    cout << "Min: " << Minimum << '\n';
    cout << "Max: " << Maximum << '\n';

    for( auto i = 1; i <= 20; ++i ) {
        if( find( begin, end, i ) == end ) {
            cout << i << "\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes please make this code with arrays. Thanks in advance.

Comment: just change 'vector<int> Array = { 15, 20, 8, 0, 17, 14, 2, 12, 10, 5 };' to 'int Array[] = { 15, 20, 8, 0, 17, 14, 2, 12, 10, 5 };'.  The global begin and end type functions also work with arrays as well.

Comment: Excuse me, what is "cbegin" and "cend" ? I don't understand. Please explain more.

Comment: can you edit your question with what your code looks now please.  I am guessing you did not #include <algorithm>

Comment: begin(), end() type functions basically give you the start of a container or the end of a container.  so begin(Array) returns &Array[0] and cbegin(Array) returns const &Array[0].

Comment: what error is it giving you and what compiler do you use?

Comment: Error: identifier "cbegin" in undefined. the same error with "cend"

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Wow! it works! Thank you so much. Can i use this one in a while loop as i wrote in my question??

Comment: yes but with your while loop your program will never end.  Also instead of doing cin >> UserInput you need to do getline(cin,UserInput) so the stream will pick up spaces...IE if you enter Dropped ones with just cin it will make UserInput equal to Dropped.  With getline it will make UserInput equal Dropped ones.

Comment: Could you please up vote and marked my answer as the answer too please.  I need all the rep I can get right now =p  If you need more help we can jump in private chat so we dont spam messages on here too.

Comment: I am a new member here. how can i vote your answer? And how can i find you if i need more help?

Comment: click the up arrow where the check mark is.  Glad I could help you!  You can find me on facebook.  I will put a link to it on my SO profile.  Feel free to send me a friend request.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because your cin gets only the first word "Dropped" instead of "Dropped ones". Seems to work just fine if you make it 1 word: http://ideone.com/AjtOc7.

If you want multiple words use getline

```
std::string UserInput;
std::getline (std::cin, UserInput);
```

Also, consider using STL library like the ones mentioned in the answers.

Comment: I tried this one, but it doesn't make the output like i want to be.

Comment: What output do you want it to be? If it is {1, 2 .. 19}, It seems to work fine. Please check the test link I have provided: http://ideone.com/AjtOc7.

Comment: I want to make a counter which print the values from 0 to 20, except the values in the array.

It means that the output should be:

1
3
4
6
7
9
11
13
15
16
18
19